# Ignore Exception at a certain Location while debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

Our Application is moving some files it requires to run during startup.

The application takes care (on shutdown) to properly stop every process using this files.

However, if the application crashes / or you just hit "stop" in VS on Debugging - some executables might still be running.

So, if you quickly restart the application, it might happen, that the copy-attempt is failing, due to the file is still in use.

For such a case, we just ignore the failed copy attempt - or more exactly: the failed deletion attempt which should make sure, that the latest version is available:

```
foreach(String entry in contents)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(entry))
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(entry);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            //ignore during this startup.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine, as there is a version of the file available for usage and the production version just ignores the exception.

The annoying Problem is, that the Debugger "breaks" everytime, this error happens.

- We don't want to generally "ignore" any `System.IO.IOException` thrown while debugging.
- We tried to annotate the method in Question with `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]` which works, but causes the exception to be catched at the callers position.

---

So, is there a way to ignore "some" exceptions raised at a certain line of code, even if general "breaking" for that kind is enabled?

Some `#if (DEBUG)`-Directives which will avoid the exception to be catched at this particular line of code?

Something like:

```
foreach(String entry in contents)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(entry))
    {
        try
        {
#if (DEBUG:NoThrow)
            System.IO.File.Delete(entry);
#endif
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            //ignore during this startup.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than a source-level solution, what about configuring MSVS?  This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017.  ALSO: You might consider subclassing your own Exception, and selectively re-throwing your "custom exception type" (including the "real" exception as a "nested exception")

Comment: @paulsm4 MSVS just shows the option "continue on unhandled"  - we would need "continue on handled" - Also, Configurations only performed in the IDE are somewhat unhandy for a bigger team - Code-based-Instructions for the debugger would solve the issue for everyone, once commited.

Comment: ps.: In this Case, we could use some more IO-Operations to avoid the exception at all - but for example a "ThreadAbortException" will be thrown everytime - and we might be only interested in it for some certain threads (while debugging)...

Comment: Sidenode, Since I tried a lot already: `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` does no longer work since VS 2015 - it will now throw/break at the callers location as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still interested in an answer, cause it has "many" usecases.

For the time beeing, we used the following "workaround": **Check, if the file has been accessed withing 3 minutes - then don't attempt to delete it. 
(For DEBUG-Mode!)**

Remember, the actual issue is only about the "debugger", not production, where Exceptions can be caught (and ignored) easily for a certain line of code.

We just want to avoid "Debugger-Breaks" kicking in if the exception can savely be ignored AT THIS line of code.

```
foreach (String entry in contents)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(entry))
    {
        try {
#if (DEBUG)
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(entry);
            if (fi.LastAccessTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3))
            {
#endif
                System.IO.File.Delete(entry);
#if (DEBUG)
            }
#endif
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //ignore
        }
    }
}
```

This is NOT a solution, it's a workaround, reducing the Debugger-Breaks at this line of code by about 99%, in case you just "Stop" Debuggin within Visual Studio!